# Response content is grey in Chrome developer tools Network tab?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

For a certain xhr network call, I am seeing the Response content is in grey in the Chrome developer tools Network tab? What does this mean? For other calls of a similar nature I am not seeing this content in grey.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it means the content on the page is being hidden.